# Is storing an encrypted cipher key in another table a good idea?

Tags: database, security, encryption, key, aes

I'm working on a project where I have valuable information that has to be stored in table 'members'. The table structure will look like this:

```
id | username | password | salt | last_name 
———|——————————|——————————|——————|———————————
 1 | VARCHAR  |   HASH   | CHAR |    BLOB   
 2 | VARCHAR  |   HASH   | CHAR |    BLOB   
 3 | VARCHAR  |   HASH   | CHAR |    BLOB   
 4 | VARCHAR  |   HASH   | CHAR |    BLOB   
 5 | VARCHAR  |   HASH   | CHAR |    BLOB
```

In this example, `last_name` is encrypted with a key. That key is stored in table 'keys':

```
id | key  
———|—————— 
 1 | BLOB 
 2 | BLOB 
 3 | BLOB 
 4 | BLOB 
 5 | BLOB
```

These keys are also encrypted with another key, that is derived from the unhashed password, the id and the username.

I thought this was save, because if the database gets stolen, the thieves cannot derive the keys in table 'keys', and ultimately cannot derive decrypt the `last_name`.

I wanted to be sure if this really was save, or if there's another way to store the keys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is called key wrapping and yes it's safe to do, but when you're encrypting your keys you should use a cipher specifically designed for it. [This question](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/1107/why-do-we-need-special-key-wrap-algorithms) has a decent explanation as to why.

Not sure what language you're using, but in Java you'd do it like this:

```
Key rootKey = new SecretKeySpec(keyBytes, "AES");
KeyGenerator generator = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");
generator.init(128);
Key keyToWrap = generator.generateKey();

Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AESWRAP");
cipher.init(Cipher.WRAP_MODE, rootKey);
byte[] wrappedKey = cipher.wrap(keyToWrap);

Cipher uncipher = Cipher.getInstance("AESWRAP");
uncipher.init(Cipher.UNWRAP_MODE, rootKey);
Key unwrappedKey = uncipher.unwrap(wrappedKey, "AES", Cipher.SECRET_KEY);
```

Also be sure to use a good key derivation function such as SCrypt to derive each users root key. [Bouncy Castle](http://www.bouncycastle.org/) has SCrypt implementations for both Java and C#, as well as it's own key wrap implementations. Or a you can find a PHP SCrypt implementation [here](https://github.com/DomBlack/php-scrypt).

**Do keep in mind** though, given your scheme, if a user forgets their password you won't be able to recover their encrypted data because the their root key is derived from the password.

Comment: I actually wanted to use 275000 iterations of the SHA-512 hashing algorithm to generate the derived key (the key to unlock the wrapped one). The wrapped key consist of 512 bytes of random characters. Is it still save?

Comment: SHA-512 is easier to optimize for cracking with a GPU than SCrypt is, and SCrypt's parameters allow you to adjust both the amount of CPU it uses as well as memory. You'd be ok with SHA-512, but SCrypt is a better choice.